# compute outerHeight with margins at parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

Given

```
<div id="parent>
  <div id="child" style="height:10px;margin:5px;padding:2px"></div>
</div>
```

I want to compute the height of the parent (including margins). I can't manage to find a proper way of doing that.

```
console.log($('#parent').outerHeight());        //= 14
console.log($('#parent').outerHeight(true));    //= 14
console.log($('#parent')[0].offsetHeight);      //= 14
console.log($('#parent')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height); //=14

//but
console.log($('#child').outerHeight());         //= 14
console.log($('#child').outerHeight(true));     //= 24 !!
```

Here's the jsfiddle to it: https://jsfiddle.net/estani/w0ro2Lsw/3/

Comment: The parent doesn't have margins, it's just 14 pixels high

Comment: try to fix [margins collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) Then your code should be like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yurzui/w0ro2Lsw/4/)

Comment: This works https://jsfiddle.net/w0ro2Lsw/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margins of the child element are outside the parent element. But they're not margins *of the parent element*, that's why outerHeight does not notice them.

The best way to find the height of parent + margin of child depends on your use case:

- If the child is the only element inside parent, and you want to use the margin to make the parent bigger than the child, I'd suggest giving `padding:5px` to the parent rather than `margin:5px` to the child.
- Adding `overflow:auto` will make the parent contain the child's margin.
- If you want the child and the parent to share the margin, give `margin:5px` to the parent.

In all of these cases, outerHeight will return the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your child div is overflowing parent div. You can use this in your parent div:

```
overflow:auto
```

example code:

```
<div id="parent" style='overflow:auto'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent "`display:inline-block;`"

[This is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0ro2Lsw/6/)